# Failed to delete temp files after running spark-submit on windows 7

Tags: scala, apache-spark, windows-7, spark-submit

I'm using the code in [this](https://github.com/tdas/spark-streaming-external-projects/tree/master/kafka) example to run a scala program using spark. The program executes fine, but when the StreamingContext tries to stop I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: ..\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-53b87fb3-1154-4f0b-a258-8dbeab6601ab
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deleteRecursively(Utils.scala:1010)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1951)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
```

I have changed nothing from the code. Just cloned it to my local file system, run `sbt assembly` command to generate .jar file, and then run the program using `spark-submit`.

Also, I'm running windows cmd as Administrator so I don't think it is a privileges issue.

Any clues on what's causing this error?

Thanks for help!

Comment: same for me.. currently no solution  - following..

Comment: @Mohammad Zammam Any solution was found?

Comment: @Li3ro I am getting same exception while running spark-submit, when i am trying to the temp directory , i am able to delete same but again when i run the command i get exception with new temp directory created.    Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: no fix yet.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think spark app creates temporary staging file in your local system (Probably when checkpoint is called) and when context is stopped tries to clean up temporary files and not able to delete. There 2 option there either file already deleted or there no privileges to delete.

Comment: Hi @FiagB. I believe it is not a privileges issue because I run the command prompt in administrator mode. I'm not sure though if spark should have also some privileges in order to delete temporary generated files.

Comment: I don't think it is a privilege issue either. I have the same issue when I exit spark-shell, or when I run any of the examples. I tried changing the working dir with --conf spark.local.dir, but the problem wasn't solved. If anyone has a solution, please share.